# Abrir link em uma nova guia sem o target ou window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Tenho uma função que faz um redirecionamento:

```
vm.pagarUpload = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: API.url + 'app/service.php?t=pagarUpload',
        data: {
            nome: vm.nomeUpload,
            email: vm.emailUpload,
            cpf: vm.cpfUpload
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('redirecionando...');
        window.location.href = "https://minhaurl.com/payment.html?code=" + response.data;
    });
}
```

Mas preciso que ao invés de direcionar para outra página abra em outra aba, não posso usar o target direto na tag `<a>` pois preciso da resposta do POST. Também não posso utilizar o `window.open('http://url...','_blank')` pois é detectado como pop-up e é bloqueado. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com `window.location` não vai ser possível porque ele referencia somente a mesma página. Você pode criar um link dinânimico no retorno do ajax com `target=_blank` e clicar nele:

```
vm.pagarUpload = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: API.url + 'app/service.php?t=pagarUpload',
        data: {
            nome: vm.nomeUpload,
            email: vm.emailUpload,
            cpf: vm.cpfUpload
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = "https://minhaurl.com/payment.html?code="+response.data;
        link.target = '_blank';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        delete link;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso usando `window.open` mesmo com uma variável, e depois do retorno do Ajax, redirecionar o conteúdo da aba/janela aberta. Isso evita que o navegador bloqueie a popup.

No link você insere o `window.open` com uma variável:

`<a href="#" onclick="janela = window.open()">Abre nova aba/janela</a>`

No Ajax você redireciona a URL da `janela`:

```
janela.location.href = "https://minhaurl.com/payment.html?code=" + response.data;
```

Código:

```
vm.pagarUpload = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: API.url + 'app/service.php?t=pagarUpload',
        data: {
            nome: vm.nomeUpload,
            email: vm.emailUpload,
            cpf: vm.cpfUpload
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('redirecionando...');
        janela.location.href = "https://minhaurl.com/payment.html?code=" + response.data;
    });
}
```

### EDIT

Você pode criar uma página `.html` padrão com o texto "Abrindo..." ou "Redirecionando..." na popup antes do retorno do Ajax, para avisar o usuário que a página está sendo processada:

`<a href="#" onclick="janela = window.open('aguarde.html')">Abre nova aba/janela</a>`